# Jsoup eats extra information of DocType if it includes a linebreak

Tags: jsoup

When I want to println a downloaded file using Jsoup some information from the DocType are missing if there is a linebreak in it. Is this intended or is this a bug?

For example:

The DocType looks like that:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And if I print it using doc.html() or doc.toString() I get:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

If there is no linkebreak in it I get the complete DocType including all information.

What can I do to solve that?

Cheers
Bene

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a bug. Thanks for pointing it out. The tokeniser wasn't correctly ignoring whitespace between the doctype name and the public identifier.

I've [fixed the bug](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/70b2cf9a73e38bd3831a8e196c84556275c3f588) and it will be available in [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem can be solved by bypassing the parser:

```
org.jsoup.Connection con =Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT).timeout(MAX_TIMEOUT).followRedirects(true);
Response resp = con.execute().method(Method.GET);
completeFile = resp.body();
doc = resp.parse();
```

Now you got the unfiltered/unparsed code in the variable "completeFile" and the nicely parsed one in the Document "doc".

I hope this could be a help for somebody.

Cheers Bene